# Memoize doesn't work for fibonacci example

Tags: clojure

```
(time (fib 30))
;; "Elapsed time: 8179.04028 msecs"

;; Fibonacci number with recursion and memoize.
(def m-fib
  (memoize (fn [n]
             (condp = n
               0 1
               1 1
               (+ (m-fib (dec n)) (m-fib (- n 2)))))))

(time (m-fib 30))
;; "Elapsed time: 1.282557 msecs"
```

This the example code from https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/memoize, but when I run it on my browser, the time doesn't change at all. I am wondering why it is?
[image]

Comment: In your browser?

Comment: The screenshot shows 2 different times

Comment: Note also that `time` result the value of the expression being computed, not the time.

Comment: The times in the picture exactly match the times in the plain text code. Did you mean to post a picture of the browser times?

Comment: trying both in cider on emacs as well as on a [browser based repl](https://repl.it/repls/ScentedMeanBackend) and `time` works fine. What is your platform, system, setup?

Comment: The time is printed, not returned. What is printed does not change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what browser-based REPL you're using, but the left-hand column shows the result of the function call, not the time, which is why both values are the same. Both functions compute the same Fibonacci number.

The `time` macro is designed to wrap arbitrary expressions without having to change the structure of the code, so it returns the same value that's returned by the wrapped expression and prints the execution time to standard out. Essentially, the expression `(time (m-fib 30))` is expanded to

```
(let [start (. System (nanoTime))
      ret (m-fib 30)]
  (println (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start)) 1000000.0) " msecs"))
  ret)
```

So to see the execution time in your REPL, you'll need to see the printed output of an expression.